# Onclick background color change and save in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have a row which contains bill fields. If the bill is paid than the admin will press "paid " button. The result will be change of entire background color of that row and that color will save in db. Now the problem is how should i save the background color of that row in database.

Here is the code which is changing background color but not saving in database.

```
function mark_complete(i){
         if(confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed with this action?')){
            $('tr').click(function () {
                if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
                    $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css('background', 'white');
                }
            });
         }
}
```

Comment: SO community is not here for write code for you. Show your effort and update your answer with what you tried so far??

Comment: @iNullPointer I mentioned my code which is changing the background color of that row now i am confused how i should save in db and make that color permanent even the url reloads again.

Comment: Okay, now whats the problem

Comment: Now I want to save the color permanently even the page reloads repeatedly.

Comment: The flag that you have to save into database should be `paid` of boolean instead of `background-color` of string.

Comment: As Chaska mentionned, in your database, you should have a status for each row... something like "paid", "completed", "billed", etc... When you display your rows, you simply add a CSS class to your row depending on the status of the row. Never save the color inside the database. That is bad architecture. The color should be manages in CSS with classes. Imagine if you wan to change "paid" from red to dark red... you'll have to update all your database for a color change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using PHP as a server language.
To start we will create ajax function to call a PHP script.
You will create a file for inserting your values in your db. I will name it for example addColor.php

```
function mark_complete(i){
         if(confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed with this action?')){
            $('tr').click(function () {
                if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
                    $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
                    $.ajax({     
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'addColor.php',
                        data: {color:'yellow'},
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);   
                        },
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css('background', 'white');
                    $.ajax({     
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'addColor.php',
                        data: {color:'white'},
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);   
                        },
                    });
                }
            });
         }
}
```

addColor.php

```
if(isset($_POST['color'])){
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $con = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_databasename);
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE `color_tbl` SET `color` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $color);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Hope this help and give you some idea